# Polymer paper-button within an a tag - display problems

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, polymer

I am using version 0.5.5 of Polymer. I am clicking on a paper-button that brings up a new browser tab as a result. When I go back to the original tab, the clicked buttons shadow is displayed incorrectly. A click anywhere in the tab corrects it.  The html for each button is as follows:

```
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web" target="_blank">
    <paper-button raised="" noink>
        <core-icon src="/assets/mdn.png"></core-icon><p>MDN</p>
    </paper-button>
</a>
```

Unfortunately, I can't post an image here due to rules of the site, but you can view it here for the "VIEW ON GITHUB" button: http://opus1269.weebly.com/about.html  Any ideas about what the problem may be?

Comment: that is usual behavior for a raised paper-button

Comment: I don''t believe it is usual behavior to leave it raised after the click is complete. Interestingly, you can duplicate a similar problem on the main Polymer page: Press and hold the left mouse button on the "GET POLYMER" button then drag the cursor off of it and release the mouse button. Everything looks OK. Now minimize the browser and bring it back up and the button is drawn with a large shadow. Click anywhere on the window and it returns to normal.  I suspect it has something to do with not getting the mouse-up event correctly. I am doing all this with Chrome on Windows 8.1.

Comment: i say this is usual behavior because it is all i have ever seen it do. all the demo buttons on polymer project do the same thing.  in chrome on elementary os / firefox on elementary os / chrome os / android and iphone as well.

Comment: Indeed, seems like a bug in Polymer itself - or a deliberate design choice not explained well. See https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/issues/46